# Bloom Filter char based

Tags: algorithm, hash, bloom-filter

I am new to Bloom Filter. I understand how to implement a Bloom Filter with bit array, which we hash value x with k hash functions and set each bit array index to 1.

But I am wondering how we are going to implement a Bloom Filter with a char array? Especially if the input is a string. One way I can think of is adding the ASCII value of each char of string and hash that value then set index of char array to some value (I am also not sure what value to set in char array if I use this method because it can't be just 0 or 1 since we are not using bit array), but the probability of false positive is going to be very high. May someone give me some ideas to get the start? (I do not need actual code, but I really appreciate if you can give me some insight on what hash function to use and how to map them into char array)

Comment: I am going to use C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some hashing algorithm which will convert that to an integer hash and then consider each bit of it as part of the bit array or char array.

```
hash(S)=sum(S[i]*(p^i))_i=0 to n-1.
```

You can use this hash 2 times to reduce the chance of false positives. That will give you a reasonable behavior.

Also choice of `p` must be limited to prime and it should be greater than the number of characters in the alphabet set.

- This will give you a better result than simple ascii value addition.

Also a strange thing is the hash functions used should independent and uniformly distributed.

Also being fast is another criteria that's why standard cryptographic hashes are not good choice. (like sha1)

One standard hashing method that I heard is `murmurhash` which you can try to use and compare with the result you expect.

**To be clear on how you will go about implementing it:-**

> You can consider multiple hash functions like `murmur`, `fnv1a` or
>   even the simple one I presented and then you get 3 values from each
>   hash. Put them in appropriate positions. And then that will work as
>   your bloom filter.

Here as you are implementing different hash functions the probability of false positive will depend on multiple hash functions resulting in a better result.

For example:

You want to hash `stackoverflow`. Now you use 3 hash functions which give you numbers 11, 45 and 17. You would keep an map where you will put this value.

```
{
   11: 1,
   45: 1,
   17: 1
}
```

Again you hash this way and get the value 11, 15 and 97.

Then you will change it to

```
{
  11: 1,
  15: 1,
  17: 1,
  45: 1,
  97: 1
}
```

> **Note**: I have mentioned map here...it can be something like a bit array also where you set the bits. For example..in case of
>   `stackoverflow` 11,17,and 45 th bits will be set to 1.

Note this map will help you answer the query whether an element is there or not.

Now in case of query , you will do the same, get the hash values and will check if these values exist. If yes there is a high chance it is there(not exactly as it may be a false positive) , if not then it is not for sure.

Suppose now you will check if string "abcd" is there. You apply the 3 hash functions used earlier. Results are 11,99,55. You will check if all 3 of them exists. You can see 55 is not there. So string "abcd" is not there.

Comment: Does that mean I should set certain index of char array to be this hash value? If so, how do I determine which index to put? (With bit array B, it will just be B(h1(x)) = 1, B(h2(x)) = 1 for each hash function, but I do not know what to do with char array)

Comment: look char array is basically collection of char's. Now the whole char array is a string. So you convert that whole thing to an int by using the hash method i mentioned. Then out bloom filtering on that integer. @ZhiyuanRuan

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Check my answer..I mopdified

Comment: I just saw your modified answer. I get your points now but I am still not sure how to choose appropriate location to put. Is it possible for you to elaborate on that?

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: I will try..wait

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Check my answer..it is simple but will explain the idea

Comment: Thanks. If my understanding of your answer is correct, does it mean we will need additional space such as a map to store hash value? If so, it seems to me we do not really use the char array since we have something like a map to track hash value and their positions.

Comment: But won't this additional space make our original char array pointless since we are not using this char array for anything?

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Otherwise you can't do anything regarding bloom filter...those char arrays are just striings..imputs..nothing else...you can allocate them duymnamically and then delete it after it's done

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one last question, how do we decide which position to put hash values? It can't be random since it will be hard to search if certain values exists. In your example, you put all value on location 1 since they are from same string. But when we check if a string exists, how do we decide which location to check (For example, how do we know we need to check location 1 for "stackoverflow") It seems to me we need another function to decide which location to put.

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Suppose you want to check if "stackoverflow" exists.... or not? It would get it's hash values,..11,45,17...and then you will check if those are there in the map...and taht's it. Now you know that there is a high chance that stackoverflow is there

Comment: I am wondering if we use additional space, doesn't it kind of losing the point of using bloom filter since the value we add in will grow unlike a typical bloom filter which use fixed space?

Comment: We may use some additional space but the time to answer the query would be faster

Comment: Is it possible to not use any additional space but only with bloom filter of m chars?

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: I dont understand how can you use it with m chars...you are hashing the strings not characters...

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Look like you said in your question...instead of map you can use bitfield also...where you access each of the bits...that way it can also be done

Comment: @ZhiyuanRuan.: Check the answer.. I have added something regarding implemenation

Comment: Thanks. I see your points with bit array. What I am asking is how to do it with char array and without a map (or any other additional space)

Comment: Just tell me what is your input?

Comment: My input is a string such as "aab"

Comment: Now look..after you get "aab"..you will hash it using different  hash functions and then you will store them in some place. Where to place them? Somehow you will set a bit in a series of bit...and that will be the thing you will need..once you are done you can stop using that char array and remove it....it doesn't matter.